# PHP preg_replace, remove word with numbers and "/"

Tags: php, regex

I am new in PHP and I'd like to ask how I am able to achieve this

from:

> workshop/559536292/hns_devblocks_v5

to:

> hns_devblocks_v5

'
Through preg_replace I have tried something , but it removed only word "workshop".

```
preg_replace('/\bworkshop/', ' ', $str);
```

Can someone help me with "tags"? Thanks

Comment: fyi "_but it removed only word "workshop"_" It wasn't removed, it was replaced with a space char.

Comment: Hi, if my answer helped you, would you please consider accept it as correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

There is no regex needed to get the last part of the path.

```
basename('workshop/559536292/hns_devblocks_v5');
```

will give

> hns_devblocks_v5

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that is in string:

$serverInfo2['Map'] = "workshop/559536292/hns_devblocks_v5"

Comment: You also can pass a string variable to basename().  `basename($serverInfo2['Map']);`